# Equation of a circle whose radius and tangent is given

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Equation of a circle which passes through the origin, whose radius is $a$ and for which $y = mx$ is a tangent.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you write the equation of a circle that passes through the origin?  Can you ask a question?

Comment: Oh yes i can... it is x^2 + y^2 +2hx + 2ky = 0 having center at (-h,-k) and with radius a = (h^2 + k^2)^1/2

Comment: OK, the tangent is perpendicular to the radius at the point of tangency.  You should know the equation for a line through the origin and perpendicular to $y=mx$. That gives you another equation for $h,k$

Comment: In this case origin is not the center. So i don't see any logic behind getting equation of perpendicular line from origin to y=mx

Comment: Draw a picture. Note that the point of tangency must be the origin. So, as in the comment by Ross Millikan, the line joining $(-h,-k)$ to the origin is perpendicular to the line $y=mx$.

Comment: The origin will be the point of tangency, because it is common to the circle and the tangent.  So the perpendicular line goes through the center.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ...

Comment: $y= m x$ will _never_ be tangent to a centered circle. A tangent line will have all its points _outside_ the circle and the origin is inside the circle while belonging to the line also. Please rephrase the question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with question. The final equation will be [(1+m^2)^1/2](x^2+y^2) -2max +2ay =0.          #Ja72

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

[image]

The center of the circle stay on the stright line orthogonal to $y=mx$ passing thorough the origin, and the distanche of the center from the origin is $\overline{OC}=a$.

How many circle can you find?